# A completely free and open programming language

Tags: programming-languages, foss

With Oracle vs Google trial, it seems that Java is not entirely Open and free (as free software) as I expected. Although there exists completely free/open JVM, it's hard to know what is a copyright infringement with Java, and what is not.

So I'd like to know if there is a completely Open and free language with open and free IDE (Eclipse-like) out there, Object Oriented if possible, and able to make window-based applications for the main OSs (Linux, Mac, Windows).

Comment: What about plain old C?

Comment: C++ and Python are the obvious examples, Mono fits, if Microsoft keeps up with their [promise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Community_Promise).

Comment: The ruling in "Oracle vs Google" was that there is **no copyright infringement**.  "a federal judge who recently finished presiding over the six-week Oracle v. Google trial ruled that the structure of the Java APIs that Oracle was trying to assert can't be copyrighted at all."

Comment: @vartec it seems from what I've read that Google still owes Oracle 150'000$ for 9 lines of codes, not much but still there.

Comment: "free and open" does **not** guarantee that it doesn't infringe some kind of patent of a third party (that's one of the big problems with current patent law, IMO). And if it's not carefully enforced it doesn't even guarantee that it doesn't infringe some copyright claim (even 'though the recent ruling added at least some measure of sanity into this).

Comment: @JoachimSauer: patents and copyright are completely separate things. And even so, it does not affect developers, other than developers of the language implementation itself.

Comment: @vartec: I know that they are separate, but they are related. And it does effect the users of the language implementation, if the developers can no longer offer/support it.

Comment: Yes. Perl. And many others.

Comment: The problem with patents is that they can affect any programming language, even those that are in no way based on what patent holder developed since similar problems often lead to similar but independently invented solutions. Only really old programming languages are reasonably safe from this, since patents covering them either expired, or it would be prior art.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Python**

The reference implementation, CPython, is released under the [Python Software Foundation License](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/license/), an [OSI approved licence](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/category). There are bindings for most popular platform-independent GUI toolkits, [including](http://docs.python.org/faq/gui.html):

- Tkinter
- wxWidgets
- Qt
- Gtk+
- FLTK
- FOX
- OpenGL

As for an IDE, since you mentioned Eclipse, [PyDev](http://pydev.org/) is probably what you're looking for. I prefer [ActiveState's Komodo IDE](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide), but it's not free.

**C++**

The core language and the standard library are ANSI/ISO standards, and although not strictly an open source language, all major C++ compilers are free to use:

- [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/), open source, and available for Windows through [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/),
- Microsoft's C++ compiler, proprietary, freely available through [Visual C++ 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express),
- Intel's C++ compiler, proprietary, [freely available for non commercial use](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/non-commercial-software-download/).

There are quite a few open source bindings / interfaces for most popular platform-independent GUI toolkits, just pick one and search for it. As for an IDE, well, [Eclipse with CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/callisto/c-dev.php) would be my choice.

**Mono**

Mono is multi-licensed under the MIT licence, GPLv2 and LGPLv2. When it comes to Microsoft's patents, insofar they've followed [their promise](http://www.microsoft.com/openspecifications/en/us/programs/osp/default.aspx), but who knows what the future will bring. Mono allows you to work with a [variety of open source GUI](http://www.mono-project.com/Gui_Toolkits) toolkits, and [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) seems to be the IDE of choice.

**FreePascal**

FreePascal is a Pascal / Object Pascal compiler, licensed under the GPL. The [Lazarus Component Library (LCL)](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Lazarus_Documentation#LCL_-_Lazarus_component_library) and [fpGUI](http://fpgui.sourceforge.net/) are the more popular FreePascal GUI toolkits, and [Lazarus](http://lazarus.freepascal.org/) the IDE of choice.

Comment: The official ISO C++ standard is not free, but a [draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) that's close enough to the released standard is free-as-in-beer -- and as you say there are several free implementations.

Comment: @KeithThompson The standard is free, you pay for the publication medium.

Comment: clang (http://clang.llvm.org/) is open source too, and more open than gcc ont the licence.

Comment: @YannisRizos: The "publication medium" is a 5-megabyte downloadable PDF file ([available from the ANSI store](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=INCITS%2fISO%2fIEC+14882-2012) for $30 US).

Comment: @KeithThompson The fee pays the people who typeset the document, the servers that host it, etc, that doesn't mean the standard itself is not free. Could they charge a lot less, or give it away for free? Yes they could and they probably should...

Comment: @YannisRizos: The fact that you can't get a copy without paying money for it means it's not free.

Comment: @KeithThompson We're arguing semantics, let's agree to disagree ;)

Comment: @YannisRizos: Apparently we're arguing about the meaning of the word "free"; I have no idea what definition you're using. I agree to disagree with you.

Comment: @KeithThompson My definition is that other than the small publication & distribution fee, you don't need to pay to actually use the standard, you can build as many compilers as you want based on it, without paying anyone anything. It's the use of the standard I care about, not getting it once.

Comment: @YannisRizos: The standard *document* clearly is not free. That's all I meant. I understand that many things associated with or derived from the standard are free.

Comment: What about Ruby?

Comment: Nothing about the good old C? :(

Comment: @Nick The question asks for object oriented languages.

Comment: @faif I have my issues with Ruby, I _really_ don't like it ;) Feel free to add it in the answer, if you feel it will make it more complete.

Answer (score 2):

Would Mono with MonoDevelop be what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could make use of a functional programming language. **Haskell** is an example. it's free.

Comment: You know of a good IDE for Haskell?

Comment: Unfortunately i don't. I'm a noob in Haskell. But i read on their website that there are many free IDE's.

Comment: Most people use Emacs or Vim to work with Haskell. There are external tools like ghc-mod and scion that provide IDE-like features to both Emacs and Vim.  There are also EclipseFP and Leksah, but I think you're far better off with Emacs.

Answer (score 2):

The [D programming language](http://dlang.org) is open source (at least if using the open source gdc and ldc compilers, see [info on this here](http://dlang.org/faq.html#q5)). It was designed to fix the deficiencies in C++, such as adding (optional) garbage collection and making the language a lot simpler and safe to use, while still being statically compiled for optimal performance.

It is thus combines of the best of two worlds: (almost) script-like syntax, with the performance of statically compiled language.

In addition the transition should be easy for C/C++/Java/C# coders, due to the many syntax similarities. Since you seem to come from Java, be sure to read the "[D for Java programmers](http://www.prowiki.org/wiki4d/wiki.cgi?JavaToD)" page, to get you started.

It has good IDE support on Linux through the [Mono-D plugin](http://mono-d.alexanderbothe.com/) for [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com) (Functioning debugging and code completion, and syntax highlighting of course).